# data table is responsive differently on window resize and refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I am using two data table on tabs. when I resize the window, it is behaving proper as i have written the script on window.resize. By default, script is also on document.ready function so when refresh the same page it shows different format.
I am adding image to demonstrate it. This is when window resized..

[image]

And this one is when refreshed (Same Size)

[image]

Here is my js

```
$(window).on('load resize',function(){ 
    $('.data-table_1').DataTable({ 
    "paging": true, 
    "info": true, 
    "responsive": true, 
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": ["no-sort"] }],     "bInfo": true }); 

$('.data-table_2').DataTable({ 
    "paging": true, 
    "info": true, 
    "responsive": true, 
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": ["no-sort"] }],     "bInfo": true }); 

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) { 
    $('.data-table:visible').each(function(e){
    $(this).DataTable().columns.adjust().responsive.recalc(); 
    }); 
});
```

and my HTML started

```
//My first Table
<table class="display data-table data-table_1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="table1">
    <thead><tr><th>Order Id</th><th>Partner</th><th>Price</th><th>paypal transaction id</th><th>View</th></tr></thead><tbody>
    //MY Content
    </tbody>
</table>

//My Second Table
<table class="display data-table data-table_2" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="table2">
   <thead><tr><th>Transaction Id</th><th>Paypal Payer Id</th><th>Transaction Time</th><th>Amount</th><th>Refund Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>
   //My content
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: instead of resize event and doc ready, try: `$(window).on('load resize', handler);`

Comment: it is giving me two alert
DataTables warning: table id=table1 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

and second
DataTables warning: table id=table2 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

Comment: Sorry but i cannot help you more just by seeing images but absolutely no code...